# How to build Urban Airship PhoneGap on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, urbanairship.com

I'm new to PhoneGap.

I'm trying to implement Urban Airship ( https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/ ) in my project.

I followed the tutorial and finished with building the app on PhoneGap build (online).
But it seems that cloud-based phonegap build ( build.phonegap.com ) does not support urban airship.

Or am I missing something here?

If so, how can I build this UA app (ios and android) on my Windows 7 machine?

Thanks

Comment: I did a implementation with UAship to Android.  Is it what you are looking for in regards to explanation ?  Well, first of all, the tutorial on the UAship website will definitely give you a head start

Comment: Thanks for reading. I did as the tutorial says, but what I'm stuck with is the .ipa and .apk files.How can I build them? Does build.phonegap.com do the job? Thanks again

Comment: iOS = Get a Mac, Android = Build locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always install [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) That will allow you to build your .ipa and .apk on you local machine. However with the Adobe cloud solution you should be able to download your applications by clicking on the buttons at the bottom of your apps admin page.

[image: buttons]

It also looks like you need to include the UA native plugin code.

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push.git
```

This will add the plugin for Cordova on your local machine. You can take a look at the available plugins on the [plugins page](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins). A quick search did not turn up anything for UA. You can also submit plugins for approval here. However the plugin must be licensed under the MIT or Apache 2.0. Which it looks to be. Once the plugin is approved I assume you can just add the plugin to your config.xml file.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.urbanairship.plugin" version="1.0.0" />
```

Comment: Thank you Shaun. Yes I did download the android application (.apk), installed it on samsung device, but the problem is it didn't connect to Urban Airship (no APID has been added on UA Dashboard). That's why I'm asking whether building this plugin ( https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push/ ) with PhoneGap cloud does successfully work or not. I'm confused because Urban Airship is not listed in Adobe PhoneGap plugins. Any advice may help. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you Shaun. Submitting the plugin could be a complicated process. What I can't figure out, what I can't find in any tutorial, is how to build this plugin?? How everyone else using this plugin build their apps? UA has rich docs, I've read them more than 100 times(PhoneGap page) but can't find out how to build .apk and .ipa! Thanks a lot

Comment: I have not used plugin myself. However I believe the node added to your config.xml will tell Cordova to compile the plugin package into your app.

Comment: @user3598040 did you ever get this plugin working on build.phonegap.com? Or did you end up compiling on your local machine?

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I'm sure the steps you provided would work, but not for me as I'm beginner. I tried phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push.git as suggested, and successfully added the plugin to my project, but phonegap build did not read it, of course because it is not yet supported. I don't know if there are other ways to build it using phonegap build (cloud) without submitting the plugin. Anyway, I moved to pushwoosh.com, they have a submitted plugin on phonegap build, I made it work in few minutes. I wish UA submit their plugin to phonegap a day